# Isomorphic apps without breaking views apart

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

I've been building single page applications on MEAN stack for the last couple of years and love it. However, the lack of SEO by default, and sometimes some performance issues are a real problem for me. So I've started looking into building isomorphic apps. I checked out these tutorials:

http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

http://engineering.devmag.io/post/1/creating-an-isomorphic-blogging-app-using-react-and-flux

With my current SPA builds, I have a master index.html file (containing body & head, header, footer, nav and scripts to load), then I have a directory of views which are loaded in using Angular's `ng-view`. This is VERY easy to maintain the frontend html as all the code for a page will be in a single view file.

However the tutorials I've looked at for isomorphic builds (using React and Flux) split html into modules, each with their own file and mixed into the javascript. I find this very ugly and difficult to maintain. Looking at the code in output file, it's very difficult to see what the resulting page will look like. It doesn't seem very semantic and appears to go back to an old fashioned way of building modular html in PHP applications that some people used to do.

Is there a way to maintain the simple routing and html view structure we've enjoyed from Angular SPAs, whilst having it able to render on the server in an isomorphic way?

Note I'm not looking simply to render the content on the server using something like PhantomJS. I still want the full isomorphic experience, where first hit to a page serves fully rendered content, then subsequent interactions execute javascript on the client side.

Comment: Certainly sounds like it would be **possible** to have it work the way you want, but i don't know of any frameworks that actually do it that way.

Comment: With React you cannot avoid mixing the HTML with JavaScript. It takes a few minutes to get used to but after those minutes then it really doesn't matter any more since you'll be thinking in components and screens rather than templates, controllers and models.

Comment: React is all about components. Each component should be its own file. They're not that different to directives with inline templates. You will soon become one of the thousands of people that HATED JSX for a week and now wouldn't have it any other way.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I just need to make the change and grow to love it then.